# Node express cookies get not set

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I recently switched my project from normal javascript to typescript. Everything works fine so for except session handling.

This is my project setup so far:

```
Server.ts
App.ts
/db/mongo/MongoHandler.ts
```

and some other stuff but that should not matter for this problem

MongoHandler.ts has a function which connects to the mongo db and returns a promise with the mongoose.connection object.

The connection to the mongodb works fine.

Inside App.ts:

```
class App {

    public app: express.Application;
    private routes: Routes;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.config();
    }

    private config(): void {

        //define less middleware
        this.app.use(less(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

        //define static directory
        this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

        //define favicon
        this.app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'favicon.ico')));

        //add support for POST messages and cookies
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
        this.app.use(cookieParser());

        //define view engine
        this.app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
        this.app.set('view engine', 'pug');

        //mongo connection

        //session handling

        //loading config
        this.app.set('config', new ConfigHandler());

        //setup sessions
        var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
        const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);

        const mongoHandler = new MongoHandler();
        mongoHandler.connect(this.app).then(connection => {
            this.app.use(session({
                secret: 'supersecret',
                store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: connection}),
                resave: false,
                saveUninitialized: true,
                cookie: {
                    secure: false,
                    expires: expiryDate
                }
            }));
        });
        this.app.set('mongo', mongoHandler);

        //define routes
        this.routes = new Routes(this.app);
        this.routes.routes();
    }
}

export default new App().app;
```

So basically every app.use is working except for the session stuff. 
req.session is undefined at every request.

I know that I'm missing something but I can't figure it out.
It's the same code as the old javascript version which works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`app.use()` can't effectively be called inside of an asynchronously called function like that. The result is that the middleware you are adding that way will be added to the end of the middleware chain, which is too late (it should come before the routes).

To use a regular Mongoose connection, you can call `.connect()` but don't have to wait for a callback/promise. As per [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo#re-use-a-mongoose-connection):

```
// Basic usage
mongoose.connect(connectionOptions);

app.use(session({
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));
```

You need to restructure your `MongoHandler` code so you can do something similar. Alternatively, use `async/await` to wait for the connection promise to be resolved before continuing the rest of the method, or add the routes inside of the callback.

Comment: Thanks. The first part helped a lot. I resolved it with changing `mongooseConnection: <connection>` to `dbPromise: mongoHandler.connect` and return a promise in the connect function